# Why does this slide/toggle only run once?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I just can't figure out, why this slidetoggle does't work. It just runs once:

HTML:

```
<div class="text">bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
</div>
<div class="button">Show</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.text{
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.heightAuto{
    height:auto;
}​
```

FUNCTION:

```
$(function(){
    $(".button").toggle(function()

        {
            var $text = $(".text");
            var contentHeight = $text.addClass('heightAuto').height();

            $text.removeClass('heightAuto').animate({ height: contentHeight}, 500);

        }, function() {

            $(".text").animate({ height: "0"}, 500);

        });
}) ;
```

​

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QwmJP/10/

Comment: Please don't rely on jsFiddle or other external links to make your post useful. If you want to ask a question here, show us the code, tell is what you expect it to do and tell us what it's doing that you didn't expect.

Comment: Just added the code. I already used toggle. I only used a code which I found to fix it like I want it to work. But I just can't figure it out. This is my question. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

beacause the contentHeight variable is 0 again, after the first animation.

if you don't overwrite it it'll work:

```
$(function() {
    var $text = $(".text");
    var contentHeight = $text.addClass('heightAuto').height();
    $text.removeClass('heightAuto');

    $(".button").toggle(function() {    
        $text.removeClass('heightAuto').animate({
            height: contentHeight
        }, 500);

    }, function() {

        $(".text").animate({
            height: "0"
        }, 500);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QwmJP/13/

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use the following jQuery

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.text').slideToggle();
});​
```

See this live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QwmJP/12/)

Comment: This of course works. But I don't want the content that gets toggled to be display: none. I want to toggle an unknown height where the content is already "loaded" in the background, that's why I am using height: 0. But thank's for your answer!

Comment: if your code works in your question then put your code inside of a click handler for the button